# python - solve vigenere challenge

Tags: python

I am solving a vigenere encoding challenge:
I have to replace every letter in message with a letter from alphabet, while the password should be some sort of an iterator.

"Entwicklerhelden are ahving fun while coding" should be "Eotxidkmeshfleeo brf iawiog fvn wiime cpdjnh" after encoding:

These are the instructions:

> For the example above the first two characters are encoded like this:
> E is shifted by 0, because a (first character of the password) is the
> fist letter in our alphabet. n is shifted by 1 letter in the alphabet,
> because b (the second character in the password) is the second letter
> of our alphabet. So n encodes to o. Repeat that for all characters of
> the message. If the password has no letters left, start form the
> beginning.

This is my code:

```
message = "Entwicklerhelden are having fun while coding."
mes_list = [letter for letter in message]
desired_output = "Eotxidkmeshfleeo brf iawiog fvn wiime cpdjnh"

alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZ"
password = "ab"

result = []
encoded_list = [alphabet[(alphabet.find(char) + 1)] if char in alphabet else char for char in mes_list]
print(mes_list)
print("-----")
print(desired_output)
print("-----")
print("".join(encoded_list))
```

and the output is:

```
['E', 'n', 't', 'w', 'i', 'c', 'k', 'l', 'e', 'r', 'h', 'e', 'l', 'd', 'e', 'n', ' ', 'a', 'r', 'e', ' ', 'h', 'a', 'v', 'i', 'n', 'g', ' ', 'f', 'u', 'n', ' ', 'w', 'h', 'i', 'l', 'e', ' ', 'c', 'o', 'd', 'i', 'n', 'g', '.']
-----
Eotxidkmeshfleeo brf iawiog fvn wiime cpdjnh
-----
Fouxjdlmfsifmefo bsf ibwjoh gvo xijmf dpejoh.
```

as I expected, it returns the correct letter for every second letter in the code.

However, I haven't figured out a way to change the list comprehension so that it'll include it for every letter. So for now, I haven't included the password and I don't know how I would go about it.

Comment: Don't assume that everyone here knows what challenge you're talking about. Add more details please

Comment: Also, please pay attention to typos which in this case might have a devastating effect: "***ah**ving*"

Comment: that's not the issue, I just typed and apparently I shouldn't do that :-D 
I am missing a way to say "for char in password" ...

Comment: You need to implement several more things: (1) iterate through the password in cycles, (2) determine the shift amount from a letter in the password, (3) iterate through the input message and the cycled password in parallel. Each of these have already been asked and answered on Stack Overflow. (You already know the solution for (2) because you have used it in your code)

Answer (score 2):

Your `desired_output` is missing the final dot!

That said, you want to do something like this (it may be compressed in a list comprehension, but I keep the for loop for better readibility):

```
result=''
for i,m in enumerate(message):
    if m in alphabet:
        delta = alphabet.index(password[i % len(password)])
        result += alphabet[(alphabet.index(m)+delta) % len(alphabet)]
    else:
          result += m
```

Comment: The ugly :) list comprehension: `[al[(al.find(m)+al.find(pw[i%len(pw)]))%len(al)] if m in al else m for i,m in enumerate(message)]`

Answer (score 0):

```py
message =        "Entwicklerhelden are having fun while coding."
desired_output = "Eotxidkmeshfleeo brf iawiog fvn wiime cpdjnh."

alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZ"
password = "ab"

def vigenere(txt, pw=password):
    ''' Encrypt text based on the letters of a keyword.'''
    encoded_list = []
    for idx, txt_char in enumerate(txt):
        if not txt_char in alphabet:  # if char not in alphabet
            encoded_list.append(txt_char)  # append char unshifted
            continue
        pwd_char = pw[idx % len(pw)]  # if end of pw, wrap around in pw
        txt_pos = alphabet.find(txt_char)  # find char pos in alpha
        pwd_pos = alphabet.find(pwd_char)  # find pw-char pos in alpha
        enc_pos = (txt_pos + pwd_pos) % len(alphabet)  # add pos, wrap around in alpha
        encoded_list.append(alphabet[enc_pos])  # add shifted char
    return "".join(encoded_list)

print(message)
print("-----")
print(desired_output)
print("-----")
print(vigenere(message))
```

Output:
`Eotxidkmeshfleeo brf iawiog fvn wiime cpdjnh.`